# JavaScript: Changing innerHtml to a radio button value

Tags: javascript, html

in our html we have a document with a radio button and a value.

This Code opens a popup:

```
<tr>
      <td><input id="vname" name="vname"></td>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td id="eins"><button id="a1" class="button button-block"/ onclick="popup1()" name="button1">Eintragen</button></td>
    </tr>

function popup1(){
    a1.name = "b1"
    window.open('schadensausmass.html', "popup", "width=700,height=600");
    alert("t")
    }
```

This is the separate Html File (popup):

```
<form name="myForm">
    <td><input type="radio" id = "radio1" name= "gleich" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id = "radio2" name= "gleich" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id = "radio3" name= "gleich" value="3"></td>
</form>
</table>
  <button type="button" onclick="meineFunktion()"></button>
```

We want the radio button value to be set in the innerhtml of `<td id="eins">`. So we tried this.

```
    function meineFunktion() {
    if (opener.document.getElementById("a1").name == "b1"){
    window.close('schadensausmass.html')
    opener.document.getElementById("eins").innerHTML= document.myForm.elements[1].value
}
```

Unfortunately the innerHtml doesnt change. If we do it like this

```
opener.document.getElementById("eins").innerHTML="Foo"
```

the innerHTML does change. 
So the problem has something to do with `document.myForm.elements[1].value`
Any tips what could be wrong here?

Comment: what is opener?

Comment: can you provide the whole html and js code

Comment: You can remove `opener` and check this. it will definitely work

Comment: @HemantRajpoot — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: @SuperUser — Since the third code example works and uses `opener`, removing `opener` cannot solve the problem.

Comment: @JegadeshBS — I provided more code...hope this helps to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change

`document.myForm.elements[1].value`

to

`document.forms.myForm.elements[1].value`

You have to specify that you would like to get a form in the document. Make sure `myform` matches the `name` attribute of the form.

You can read more about forms and how to get its elements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input id="rdBtnDigitize" type="radio" name= "gleich" value="1">
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('#rdBtnDigitize')[0].nextSibling.data = 'Foo'
});
```